# Поставить vs класть

Tags: выбор-слова

В чем разница между словами **класть** и **поставить**?

Comment: _Класть_ — глагол несовершенного вида, _поставить_ — совершенного вида.

Comment: Мне не совсем понятен этот downvoting без объяснений,  может стоит вести себя цивильнее.  К тому же вопрос явно вызван тем, что по-английски это один глагол.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Класть (что делать?) -- глагол несовершенного вида, после этого действия предмет лежит.

> Не кладите ручку и карандаш в карман.

Поставить (что сделать?) --глагол совершенного вида, после этого действия предметы стоят.

> Поставь стакан на стол, пока не разбил.

Comment: "Поставить на ноги" vs "Класть на лопатки"

Comment: Если поставить пластинку/музыку, то что тогда будет соять? ))

Comment: "Поставить пластинку" из разряда  устойчивых выражений,  их довольно много

Comment: Интересный момент: "Поставить стакан" vs "Поставить тарелку". Тарелку "поставить" ввиду её формы, можно только на ребро, ан нет, хоть и "ложат", но "ставят" всё же.